# How do you auto-check a checkbox or radio-button on a fillable pdf, using pdfrw or some other python tool such as pypdf?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfrw

While using pdfrw, I am able to update all of the text fields on the fillable pdf, with no issue. (This is done using the pdfDict class within pdfrw. However, I am not able to check the checkboxes or radio buttons, via any dict value that I have tried

I have tried using a number of values for the corresponding field in the dictionary, including 1, '/1', '/On', '/Yes', and 'n', but none of them have resulted in the checkbox/radiobutton being checked.

```
key = annotation[Annot_Field_Key][1:-1]
if key in data.keys():
    annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(V = '{}'.format(data[key])))
```

I also have a dictionary containing keys consisting of the pdf field names, and values of sample values

Answer (score 1):

Try `annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(V = '{}'.format("Yes")))` instead of `"\Yes"`